# Mac toolchain seems to override the cmake settings

Tags: cmake, clion

I am trying to use the G++ compiler in my build toolchain as you can see in the image below; however, it seems like these settings are overridden by my Mac toolchain. How can I ensure that the toolchain specified in my project is being used?

When I build my project, I see it defaults to AppleClang instead of G++:

```
cmake -B build
```

-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 12.0.5.12050022

-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 12.0.5.12050022

Settings specified in CLion:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To build your project with g++ you need longer comman line like

```
"/Users/USERNAME/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/CLion/ch-0/232.9559.58/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug "-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/CLion/ch-0/232.9559.58/CLion.app/Contents/bin/ninja/mac/ninja" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/local/bin/g++-13 -G Ninja -S /Users/USERNAME/CLionProjects/untitled -B /Users/USERNAME/CLionProjects/untitled/cmake-build-debug
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 14.0.3.14030022
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 13.1.0
```

or continue compilation from IDE action.
The `cmake -B build` command is working with system defaults, not CLion defaults.